# What is the difference between string function and string constructor in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

As, I learnt these are the ways of making a string.
However , the string made using new keyword give us a object and and array as well.

### The output given by string made using new keyword:

```
                    String {'ashim kandel'
```

0: "a"
1:"s"
2: "h"
3:"i"
4:"m"
5: ""
6: "k"
7: "a"
8: "n"
9: "d"
10: "e"
11: "l"
length: 12
[[Prototype]]: String
[[PrimitiveValue]]: "ashim kandel"

However , the string made with String constructor gives us string .

### //here is the code

```
const strPrim3 = String('ashim kandel'); // Coerced into the string primitive "true"

const strObj = new String('ashim kandel); // String with new returns a string wrapper object.
```

//please tell me how things are working here

Comment: you only notice the difference if you check the variables type with `typeof` or when you compare values, `(strObj == 'ashim kandel')` gives TRUE, `(strObj === 'ashim kandel')` gives FALSE; while both `(strPrim3 == 'ashim kandel')` and `(strPrim3 === 'ashim kandel')` give TRUE https://jsfiddle.net/ev6zx58h/

Comment: Refer MDN documentation [String primitives and String objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#string_primitives_and_string_objects)